# max freq of repetition in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

what is the fastest way to find the max freq of repetition in an array in java in smallest time complexity
*A=[1,2,3,4,1,1]*

*ans = 1*

how can this be done

Comment: sorting in general case? if range of numbers is limited than with an array of counters.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991984/algorithm-for-finding-the-number-which-appears-the-most-in-a-row-c

Comment: why answer=1? 1 was repeated 3 times, the answer should be 3 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a (mostly) linear time solution would be to use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` and build a histogram of all values appearing in A.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for(int x : A)
{
    Integer v = m.get(x);
    if (null == v) {v = Integer.valueOf(0);}
    m.put(x, ++v);
}
```

The going over the entire map and return the entry with the maximum value.
with the `entrySet()` method this is done in linear time as well.